# Problema con las a etiquetas

Tags: html

Tengo una página `index.html`, es la única página con extensión `.HTML` de mi proyecto web. En ella hago referencia a varias partes de mi página usando enlaces relativos:

- `<a href="#inicio">Inicio<a/>`
- `<a href="#contacto">Contacto<a/>`

*Sección de Inicio:*

`<section id="inicio">Esta es mi sección de inicio</section>`

Al dar clic a cualquier enlace en mi barra de navegación, se ejecuta el proceso de redirección a los lugares que deseo ir en mi pagina; sin embargo pierdo las direcciones a la cual he navegado en la barra de navegación.

Ejemplo:
dado clic en `<a href="#inicio">Inicio</a>` mi en la barra de navegación debería mostrar que estoy en: `www.dominio.com/#Inicio`, hasta el momento no se muestra

En mi `footer` tengo varios enlaces que se ejecutan como deseo haciendo la respectiva redirección a los formularios. Si recargo la web aun me aparece en la barra de búsqueda `dominio.com/#contacto` no desaparece la referencia del enlace.

Uso la misma forma de redirigir y obtener los enlace, mi duda es por que sucede y como debo solucionarlo.

Comment: Por favor lee como proveer un  [mcve]

Comment: Puedes alterar el hash (#) con location.hash para que al recargar la pagina asignar el hash deseado y puedes manejar los cambios con el evento hashchange